# How to highlight duplicate reference designaters in Multilevel Bill of material

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on macro that highlights duplicate Reference designators under immediate top level of multilevel Bill of material.

[image]

My code is as below:

```
'To identify duplicates RDs
Sheet1.Columns(14).Copy (Sheet4.Cells(1, 1))

Sheet4.Select
    Sheet4.Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp
    Sheet4.Columns(1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone


    Dim FromLine As Integer
    Dim ToLine As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim Leng As Integer
    Dim RefTemp, RefTemp1, RefTemp2 As String
    Dim Cha As String
    Dim ReferenceNo As String
    Dim PartNo As String
    Dim Description As String
    Dim Flag As Boolean

    FromLine = 1
    Cha = " "
    While Cells(FromLine, 1) <> ""
        Flag = True
        ReferenceNo = LTrim(Cells(FromLine, 1))
        RefTemp = RTrim(ReferenceNo)
        Leng = Len(RefTemp)
        Cells(FromLine, 1) = RefTemp
        Count = 1
        While Count <= Leng And Flag

            RefTemp1 = Left(ReferenceNo, 1)
            If RefTemp1 <> " " And RefTemp1 <> "," Then

                ReferenceNo = Right(ReferenceNo, Leng - Count)

            Else
                Cells(FromLine, 1) = Left(RefTemp, Count - 1)
                Flag = False
                RefTemp2 = Right(ReferenceNo, Leng - Count)

                FromLine = FromLine + 1
                Rows(FromLine).Select
                Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
                Cells(FromLine, 1) = RefTemp2

                FromLine = FromLine - 1
            End If
            Count = Count + 1
        Wend
        FromLine = FromLine + 1

    Wend


    Dim cel1 As Variant
    Dim myrng1 As Range
    Dim clr1 As Long
    Set myrng1 = Sheet4.Range("A1:A" & Sheet4.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
    myrng1.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    j = 1

    For Each cel1 In myrng1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng1, cel1) > 1 Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet4.Range("A1:A" & cel1.Row), cel1) = 1 Then

                Sheet4.Cells(j, 2).Value = cel1
                j = j + 1

            Else
                cel1.Interior.ColorIndex = myrng1.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel1.Value, myrng1, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
            End If
        End If
    Next


Dim lastrow4 As Long
 lastrow4 = Sheet4.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow4
    For j = 1 To lastrow
        k1 = InStr(Sheet1.Cells(j, 14).Value, Sheet4.Cells(i, 2).Value)
        len1 = Len(Sheet4.Cells(i, 2).Value)

        If k1 > 0 Then
            Sheet1.Cells(j, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
            Sheet1.Cells(j, 14).Characters(k1, len1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Sheet4.Rows("1:" & Rows.Count).Delete shift:=xlUp


Sheet1.Select
```

Problems:

Requirement is to highlight duplicate 'Ref Des' under immediate top level.

For e.g. in above screenshot 'P2'& 'P3' is immediate childs of 'M1'  (P2 &P3 are level 2 and M1 is level 1).

So, in column N, letter J is highlighting. It is correct.

But P4 is child of M2. It must not highlight.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got solution for above problem as below:

```
'To identify duplicates RDs
Sheet1.Columns(14).Copy (Sheet4.Cells(1, 1))

Sheet4.Select
    Sheet4.Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp
    Sheet4.Columns(1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone


    Dim FromLine As Integer
    Dim ToLine As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim Leng As Integer
    Dim RefTemp, RefTemp1, RefTemp2 As String
    Dim Cha As String
    Dim ReferenceNo As String
    Dim PartNo As String
    Dim Description As String
    Dim Flag As Boolean

    FromLine = 1
    Cha = " "
    While Cells(FromLine, 1) <> ""
        Flag = True
        ReferenceNo = LTrim(Cells(FromLine, 1))
        RefTemp = RTrim(ReferenceNo)
        Leng = Len(RefTemp)
        Cells(FromLine, 1) = RefTemp
        Count = 1
        While Count <= Leng And Flag

            RefTemp1 = Left(ReferenceNo, 1)
            If RefTemp1 <> " " And RefTemp1 <> "," Then

                ReferenceNo = Right(ReferenceNo, Leng - Count)

            Else
                Cells(FromLine, 1) = Left(RefTemp, Count - 1)
                Flag = False
                RefTemp2 = Right(ReferenceNo, Leng - Count)
                'PartNo = Cells(FromLine, 2)
                'Description = Cells(FromLine, 3)
                FromLine = FromLine + 1
                Rows(FromLine).Select
                Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
                Cells(FromLine, 1) = RefTemp2
                'Cells(FromLine, 2) = PartNo
                'Cells(FromLine, 3) = Description
                FromLine = FromLine - 1
            End If
            Count = Count + 1
        Wend
        FromLine = FromLine + 1

    Wend


    Dim cel1 As Variant
    Dim myrng1 As Range
    Dim clr1 As Long
    Set myrng1 = Sheet4.Range("A1:A" & Sheet4.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
    myrng1.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    j = 1

    For Each cel1 In myrng1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng1, cel1) > 1 Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet4.Range("A1:A" & cel1.Row), cel1) = 1 Then
                'cel1.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
                'cel1.Font.ColorIndex = 1
                Sheet4.Cells(j, 2).Value = cel1
                j = j + 1

            Else
                cel1.Interior.ColorIndex = myrng1.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel1.Value, myrng1, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
            End If
        End If
    Next


Dim lastrow4 As Long
 lastrow4 = Sheet4.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 Dim myarr() As String

For i = 1 To lastrow4
    For j = 1 To lastrow

        myarr() = Split(Sheet1.Cells(j, 14).Value, ",")

        k1 = 0

        For y = LBound(myarr) To UBound(myarr)
            If myarr(y) = Sheet4.Cells(i, 2).Value Then
                k1 = 1
            End If
        Next y


        'L1 = InStr(Sheet1.Cells(j, 14).Value, Sheet4.Cells(i, 2).Value)
        len1 = Len(Sheet4.Cells(i, 2).Value)



        If Not IsEmpty(Sheet4.Cells(i, 2)) Then
            If k1 > 0 Then
                Start = 1

                Do
                 L1 = InStr(Start, Sheet1.Cells(j, 14).Value, Sheet4.Cells(i, 2).Value)

                If L1 > 0 Then
                    Start = L1 + 1
                    Sheet1.Cells(j, 14).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
                    Sheet1.Cells(j, 14).Characters(L1, len1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
                Loop While L1 > 0


            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Sheet4.Rows("1:" & Rows.Count).Delete shift:=xlUp


Sheet1.Select
```